# How to include the query filter in URL (cloudSearch)

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch

I am trying to retrieve data from cloudSearch, searching for the word "Person" and adding the following filter:

```
(prefix field=claimedgalleryid '')
```

The problem is that I don't know how to create the URL using that exact filter. 
Could someone give me a suggestion or some link to Amazon documentation related to this topic?

What I've tried and didn't work:

```
...search?q=Gallerist&size=10&start=0&fq=(prefix%20field=claimedgalleryid%20%27%27)
...search?q=Gallerist&size=10&start=0&filter=(prefix%20field=claimedgalleryid%20%27%27)
```

Comment: The searched word is not important. I need help only with the filter. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You were close with your first attempt--it looks like you forgot to URI encode the `=` sign as `%3D`. Try this instead:

`&fq=(prefix+field%3Dclaimedgalleryid+'')`

I highly recommend using the "test search" feature to work out the kinks in your query syntax.  You can see the results right there, and then use the "View Raw: JSON" link to copy the full request URL and see how characters get escaped and such.

[image: CloudSearch Test Search]

Comment: THIS IS THE ANSWER.  I've been using the test query and struggling to manually convert it to a url. I kept asking "Why isn't there a tool in the dashboard that does this for me?". I wouldn't have ever guessed that the view raw json button would hide that feature.